# NgRx TypeError: entities is not iterable

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I've been trying to implement ngrx state management in my app by following the guides on the Angular University code, so I'm trying to adapt the approach in the course's repo (https://github.com/angular-university/ngrx-course/tree/2-entity-finished/src/app/courses) to my app.

At this point, I have All actions being called correctly, by looking at the ngrx dev tools, my `global` payload gets to the client but then the app breaks with an `ERROR TypeError: entities is not iterable` and it doesn't get stored, so I'm looking for some help to figure out what is wrong here, I suspect is in the reducer but my lack of experience doesn't let me find the issue.

effects:

```
  loadStats$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(StatsActions.loadGlobalStats),
      switchMap((action) => this.service.getData()),
      tap(console.log),
      map((global) => {
        return globalStatsLoaded({ global });
      })
    )
  );
```

actions:

```
export const loadGlobalStats = createAction(
  '[Global Stats Resolver] Load Global Stats'
);

export const globalStatsLoaded = createAction(
  '[Load Global Stats Effect] Global Stats Loaded',
  props<{ global: IOccurrence[] }>()
);
```

reducer:

```
export const statsAdapter = createEntityAdapter<IStats>();

const initialState = statsAdapter.getInitialState({
  global: [],
  countries: [],
  globalStatsLoaded: false,
  currentCountry: null,
});

export const statsReducer = createReducer<StatsState>(
  initialState,

  on(StatsActions.globalStatsLoaded, (state, { global }) => {
    return { ...state, globalStatsLoaded: true, global };
  })
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where exactly does the error pop up?

Comment: how this.service.getData() looks like? I guess you use the wrontg store-selector in your service

Comment: @DonJuwe I can't exactly find out, but I suspect it's in the reducer because then action `globalStatsLoaded`performs correctly, I can see in the logs. The error log in the console is:

```
ERROR TypeError: entities is not iterable
    at addManyMutably (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33132:30)
    at Object.operation [as addMany] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33067:27)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.js:3968:264
```
I can't take nothing from here.

Comment: @enno.void it looks like this:
`return this.http.get<IOccurrence[]>(`data`)` it's a normal http request that returns and observable of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `EntityAdapter`, you should also be using the [collection methods](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods). From the docs:

> The entity adapter also provides methods for operations against an entity. These methods can change one to many records at a time. Each method returns the newly modified state if changes were made and the same state if no changes were made.

In your case, try something like this in your *reducer*:

```
on(StatsActions.globalStatsLoaded, (state, { global }) => {
    return statsAdapter.upsertOne(global, state);
})
```

Hope, this helps :-)

Comment: good suggestion, thanks, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: There might be other reducers or selectors interfering. You have to change them all like here in these examples: https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter

Comment: I guess the issue is in the Entity's model, I'll try to rebuild it by following this guide https://blog.angular-university.io/ngrx-entity/